# HTML/CSS - Align Text with Images and numbers

Tags: html, css, alignment

I know I could use float and put the image to the left, but how can I then have those numbers, the header, and those three columns?

HTML:

```
    <div class="images">
  <ul>
    <li class="image"><img src="https://www.ofbizdemo.com/images/products/PC001/large.png" />
    <p class="padding">Text Here</font>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .images ul li {
   display: inline;
}

.image {
   float: left; // float to the left
}

p.padding {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-right: 500px;
    padding-left: 150px;

}
```

I'm using that for my CSS, but my text does not get exactly aligned to the right hand side, and I'm unsure of how I can add those numbers that the picture shows.

Comment: put some code on, fiddles always best

Comment: put everything you have up and we can see whats wrong. We're not here to code the whole thing for you

Comment: @Thaddius I have done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a starting point:
**http://jsfiddle.net/wpQb9/1/**

```
.col {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 20px;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
}
.col:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 30px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: yellow;
    display: block;
}
.col:nth-child(1):before {
    content:"1";
}
.col:nth-child(2):before {
    content:"2";
}
.col:nth-child(3):before {
    content:"3";
}
p {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

.col being one of columns, a div element.

But seriously now: there are thousands of way to do it. My example is lacking: background images, proper paddings/margins, fonts(?), width of columns themself. That much please do your best to figure out. Protip: use google.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry I am still a bit of a noob, and I'm really trying to figure everything out. I appreciate your help very much and it really has helped me figure things out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use a separate DIV for each of the 3 columns.  a class for the text header and another for the text and then a class for the circle.  Border-radius to make it round and I think you can figure out the rest.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Pretty much but my only problem is that multiple lines of the text are not centered with the image. How can I do that?

Comment: use a separate div for it.  so you'll have 3 divs side by side and then each will have 2 divs inside of it for the top and bottom stuff.